How do I get '//!' comments to be colored in red in WebStorm IDE?
Just like the "Better Comments" in VS Code, I want certain comments to be colored red. comments that start with //!
I am using TypeScript JSX for React and React Native, but want this feature also to my JS files.
I asked Perplexity and tried about 6 different ways of doing that, including "scopes", but Perplexity couldn't find an answer...
I also looked at the official documentation but found no option of that sort.

You can set custom patterns in WebStorm to highlight comments in different colors.
Go to File > Settings (or WebStorm > Preferences on macOS).
Navigate to Editor > TODO.
Click the + icon to add a new pattern. //!.* in your case.
Define your custom pattern (e.g., HIGHLIGHT:) and set a color for it.

 Follow the steps as demonstrated in image attached.

Wow! Thanks! It worked!
